# How to pre-populate field in ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

Here's my `Post` model which makes up the contents of a user's post:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.TextField(max_length=76)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    content = models.TextField(null=False, default='')
    image = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, default='1')
```

Here's my form:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content = forms.CharField(widget=PagedownWidget)
    title = forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'title'})

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [
            'title',
            'content',
            'category',
            'image',
            'id',
        ]
```

And here's my view:

```
def post(request):

    allauth_login = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
    allauth_signup = SignupForm(request.POST or None)

    form_post = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form_post.is_valid():
        category = form_post.cleaned_data['category']
        for a, b in CATEGORY_CHOICES:
            if a == category:
                category = b
                form_post.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/%s' % category)
    else:
        form_post = PostForm()

    context = {
        'allauth_login': allauth_login,
        'allauth_signup': allauth_signup,
        'form_post': form_post
    }

    return render(request, 'post.html', context)
```

When the user submits the `PostForm` to submit a post, how do I automatically set the `user` field to whoever is posting?

Edit: The following code still gives a `TypeError at /post/ __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'`

```
def post(request):
    allauth_login = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
    allauth_signup = SignupForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        form_post = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES, user=request.user)
        if form_post.is_valid():
            category = form_post.cleaned_data['category']
            for a, b in CATEGORY_CHOICES:
                if a == category:
                    category = b
                    form_post.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/%s' % category)
        else:
            form_post = PostForm()

        context = {
            'allauth_login': allauth_login,
            'allauth_signup': allauth_signup,
            'form_post': form_post
        }

        return render(request, 'post.html', context)
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/accounts/signup/")
```

Answer (score 1):

The `user` is in request. So you can write:

```
user=request.user
```

Thats all

So your view should look like this

```
def post(request):

    allauth_login = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
    allauth_signup = SignupForm(request.POST or None)

    form_post = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES, user=request.user)
    if form_post.is_valid():
        category = form_post.cleaned_data['category']
        for a, b in CATEGORY_CHOICES:
            if a == category:
                category = b
                form_post.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/%s' % category)
    else:
        form_post = PostForm()

    context = {
        'allauth_login': allauth_login,
        'allauth_signup': allauth_signup,
        'form_post': form_post
    }

    return render(request, 'post.html', context)
```

UPD

it works only when user is authenticated. to check out if user is authenticated, you can add `@login_required` decorator just befor the view, for example:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
@login_required
def post(request):
  ...
```

Also, i think you have to make `if` statement, to render page for authenticated users, and not. for example

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
  form_post = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES, user=request.user)
  if form_post.is_valid():
    ...
else:
  ..
```

Comment: Where do I write that though?

Comment: `form_post = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES, user=request.user)` doesn't work, got: `TypeError at /post/

__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'`

Comment: My IDE (PyCharm) also highlights `user=request.user` as an unexpected argument

Comment: its cause your user not authenticated, it works only when user is authenticated

Comment: Like this?: `if request.user.is_authenticated and form_post.is_valid():`

Comment: I've tried your code and it's still giving the same error. I've put the code I tried in my edit.